# Custom Snippet Not Working - Sublime Text

Tags: html, sublimetext2

So i've recently picked up Sublime and it's the best editor I've ever had, hands down. That said, I'm trying to write a custom snippet for an HTML page framework, but can't seem to get it to insert properly in Sublime. It isn't kicking back any errors, and Sublime recognizes that it exists, but when I try to insert it, it doesn't do anyting....am I missing something in the snippet code here?

I used the documentation [here](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/snippets.html) while I was writing it.

```
<snippet>
<content><![CDATA[
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us">
<head>
<title>${1:WebsiteName}</title>
<meta charset="utf-8" >
<meta http-equiv="default-style" content="pref" >
<!--disables caching of the site-->
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" >
<!--other sites cannot display this page in a frame-->
<meta http-equiv="window-target" content="_top" >
<!--must be completed for SEO-->
<meta name="keywords" content="${3:keywords...}" >
<!--must be completed for SEO-->
<meta name="description" content="${4:description...}" >
<meta name="author" content="${5:your_name}" >
<!--allows bots to index website-->
<meta name="robots" content="index, follow" >
<meta name="copyright" content="${6:copyright}" >
<!--sets the revisit frequency for search bots-->
<meta name="revisit-after" content="14 days">
<!--prevents dup entries in open directory project DMOZ-->
<meta name="googlebot" content="noodp">
<!--used for age appropriateness, values: {general} {mature} {restricted} {14 years} {safe for kids}-->
<meta name="rating" content="general">
<meta name="reply-to" content="${7:webmasteremail@yoursite.com}">
<!--use the content of this to indicate the developer who created the page-->
<meta name="web_author" content="${8:your_name}">
<!--controls caching permissions, values: {Public} {Private} {no-cache} {no-Store}-->
<meta name="Cache-control" content="Public">
<!--cookie data should be dynamically handled by PHP if needed-->
<!-- <meta name="Set-Cookie" content="" -->
<meta name="host" content="Internet Connection Inc">
<meta name="host-admin" content="${9:webmaster_name}">
<meta name="contactName" content="${10:customer_name}">
<meta name="contactOrganization" content="${11:business_name}">
<meta name="contactStreetAddress1" content="${12:business_address}">
<meta name="contactZipcode" content="${13:business_zipcode}">
<meta name="contactCity" content="${14:business_city}">
<meta name="contactCountry" content="${15:business_country}">
<meta name="contactPhoneNumber" content="${16:business_phone}">
<meta name="contactFaxNumber" content="${17:business_fax}">
<meta name="contactNetworkAddress" content="${18:business_email}">
<meta name="linkage" content="${19:website_url_absolute}">
<link id="pref" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="${20:CSS_Location}" >
<!--[if lte IE 6]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="${21:CSS_Location}">
<!--[endif]-->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html15.js"></script>
<!--[endif]-->
</head>
<body>
<?php include("${22:Header_location"); ?>
<!--main HTML content goes here-->

<?php include("${23:Footer_location"); ?>
</body>
</html>

]]></content>
<tabTrigger>htf</tabTrigger>
<scope>text.html</scope>
<description></description>
</snippet>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Part 22 and 23 are not ended correctly, number 2 is missing and number 7 is strange:

```
content="${7:webmasteremail@yoursite.com}"
```

Which should be:

```
content="${7:webmasteremail}@yoursite.com"
```

This should work for you (notice that I've changed some names and made them all uppercase, but the functionality is the same):

```
<snippet>
<content><![CDATA[
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us">
<head>
<title>${1:WEBSITENAME}</title>
<meta charset="utf-8" >
<meta http-equiv="default-style" content="pref" >
<!--disables caching of the site-->
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" >
<!--other sites cannot display this page in a frame-->
<meta http-equiv="window-target" content="${2:WINDOW_NAME}" >
<!--must be completed for SEO-->
<meta name="keywords" content="${3:KEYWORDS}" >
<!--must be completed for SEO-->
<meta name="description" content="${4:DESCRIPTION}" >
<meta name="author" content="${5:YOUR_NAME}" >
<!--allows bots to index website-->
<meta name="robots" content="index, follow" >
<meta name="copyright" content="${6:COPYRIGHT}" >
<!--sets the revisit frequency for search bots-->
<meta name="revisit-after" content="14 days">
<!--prevents dup entries in open directory project DMOZ-->
<meta name="googlebot" content="noodp">
<!--used for age appropriateness, values: {general} {mature} {restricted} {14 years} {safe for kids}-->
<meta name="rating" content="general">
<meta name="reply-to" content="${7:WEBMASTEREMAIL}@yoursite.com">
<!--use the content of this to indicate the developer who created the page-->
<meta name="web_author" content="${8:YOUR_NAME}">
<!--controls caching permissions, values: {Public} {Private} {no-cache} {no-Store}-->
<meta name="Cache-control" content="Public">
<!--cookie data should be dynamically handled by PHP if needed-->
<!-- <meta name="Set-Cookie" content="" -->
<meta name="host" content="Internet Connection Inc">
<meta name="host-admin" content="${9:WEBMASTER_NAME}">
<meta name="contactName" content="${10:CUSTOMER_NAME}">
<meta name="contactOrganization" content="${11:BUSINESS_NAME}">
<meta name="contactStreetAddress1" content="${12:BUSINESS_ADDRESS}">
<meta name="contactZipcode" content="${13:BUSINESS_ZIPCODE}">
<meta name="contactCity" content="${14:BUSINESS_CITY}">
<meta name="contactCountry" content="${15:BUSINESS_COUNTRY}">
<meta name="contactPhoneNumber" content="${16:BUSINESS_PHONE}">
<meta name="contactFaxNumber" content="${17:BUSINESS_FAX}">
<meta name="contactNetworkAddress" content="${18:BUSINESS_EMAIL}">
<meta name="linkage" content="${19:WEBSITE_URL_ABSOLUTE}">
<link id="pref" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="${20:CSS_LOCATION}" >
<!--[if lte IE 6]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="${21:CSS_LOCATION2}">
<!--[endif]-->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html15.js"></script>
<!--[endif]-->
</head>
<body>
<?php include("${22:HEADER_LOCATION}"); ?>
<!--main HTML content goes here-->

<?php include("${23:FOOTER_LOCATION}"); ?>
</body>
</html>

]]></content>
<tabTrigger>htf</tabTrigger>
<scope>text.html</scope>
<description></description>
</snippet>
```

Comment: I hate when that happens...btw I kept full mail address within the brackets because it will be used by a few different developers on different websites, and we do have customers who like to handle their own websites occasionally.

Comment: In that case it should be something like `content="${7:webmasteremail}@${8:yoursite}"` and don't forget to increment all the other numbers.

Comment: No problems, some time all you need is another set of eyes, those were easy to miss.